# What OpenGL ES texture format should I use for better dynamic range on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing some software which uses a texture map to store geometry. Using GL_RGB for the internal format gives a lot of aliasing, I assume because the texture is being compressed down to GL_RGB4 by default.

On a desktop I can use GL_RGB16 or GL_RGB32F (etc.) to set the internal format, but under OpenGL ES 2.0 there doesn't seem to be any of these formats. Is there an alternative, or extension, that is available under IOS which I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple (and my own experience) GL_RGB and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE uses 8:8:8 storage. To drop to lower colour precision you'd need to specify a type of GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5 or one of the other types that packs multiple channels into one short.

If precision problems are creeping in nevertheless then it might be wise to check out the [GL_OES_texture_float and GL_OES_texture_half_float](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) extensions. You're limited to GL_NEAREST filtering, but I expect that's what you're using anyway since this is an exercise in data storage, and you can upload your source channels with 16 or 32 bits per pixel.

EDIT: example usage ripped directly from a project (which is uploading a 1 channel/pixel image, but you get the idea):

```
GLfloat *integralImage;

/* <lots of stuff to allocate storage and fill integralImage here> */

glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE,
    256, 256, 0,
    GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, 
    integralImage);
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding things here, but I thought that GL_FLOAT only specified the input format (i.e. what is being passed in).. and that internalFormat (argument 3 to glTexImage) specified how it is stored in texture memory. On my laptop if I use GL_RGB for internalFormat I get aliasing, but if I switch to GL_RGB16 or GL_RGB32F (i.e. 16/32 bits for each channel) then the aliasing goes away (both using GL_FLOAT for type).

Comment: I think possibly the meanings have drifted a little from their original intent on the desktop; at least in ES, the internal format is used just to distinguish which channels you're supplying. I can't find a statement anywhere in the ES spec that the specified input format will always be honoured by the GPU, but can tell you from experience that it will on iOS with the float extension. The project that code is taken from uploads a single channel texture with values that would cover a 24bit integer range, and I definitely get the full range back in the shader.

Comment: Oh, also, I'm unable to find an immediate definitive reference on RGB/UNSIGNED_CHAR being 8:8:8 but you can see it stated implicitly in official forum answers like https://devforums.apple.com/thread/94627?tstart=15

Answer (score 1):

So, after a bit of research, you can get float textures (as mentioned by @Tommy). What you can't do is access them from a vertex shader under IOS, making it impossible to use them to store geometry.