# How to show legally DICOM 16 unsigned integer on the device are supporting 8 bit unsigned integer?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, dicom, grayscale

I'm working on a Medical app on iOS. The iOS devices just support GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE with GL_LUMINANCE or generally just support 8 bit per component. Now I have some grayscale images are 16 bit unsigned integer and I want to show them. I find we can't show 16 bit unsigned integer and Therefore I should convert them to 8 bit unsigned integer. But in Medical I should not loss data or should have minimum data loss.

Now, my question is : how to convert 16 bit unsigned integer to 8 bit unsigned integer by a legal conversion in Medical? Now I'm using simplest way to do this. Just divide it to 256 :-O. Some other commercial softwares are doing this and they are using in action.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use float and half-float input textures in most iOS devices: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5704567/19679

Comment: I've tested float. But It's working in my iPad 2. Are you tested it successfully?

Comment: Hi! I know I'm resurrecting a really old topic, but is there a way you can share that image with BitDepth 16? I am developing an imaging app as well and need such an image to test smth. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **MUST** convert these values in order to show them applying a **Window Level**.

Grayscale Dicom images do usually have two Data Elements (Dicom fields) containing the values WC (Window Center, Data Element: 0028,1050) and WL (Window Level, Data Element: 0028,1051). These values define the linear equation necessary to display the information contained in the image.

You can find a more detailed description about the concept of Window Level [here](https://www.dabsoft.ch/dicom/3/C.11.2.1.2/).

Comment: Also, you can not always expect the DICOM elements to provide appropriate values for the window and level.  It should be considered a necessity to provide the user with a mechanism for adjusting the parameters.

Comment: I agree, but for me, the problem is the developer not knowing about the window level concept and trying to do a direct 16bit grayscale to RGB (or 8 bit grayscale) conversion without taking into consideration the possible presence of the window leveling values

Comment: There is one thing that is is suffering me : I installed MIM on my iPad and you can change level/window. But level can change beyond on 255. Now how is possible when my iPad 2 just supports GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE? For example you can change it(level) to 2000? I think changing window can be anything, but level should not be beyond  supported version in iPad.

Comment: You can bet that your iPad internally supports reading signed integers as well as unsigned ones, so it is fully capable of reading the raw Dicom image data. The software reads the raw values, makes the necessary adjustments an conversions (bit offsets, rescale, etc) and finally applies the window level in order to map a particular range of these values to the RGB space (8 bit grayscale in this case).

Comment: Now I get the concept of window/level. Thank you guys. But I think this is unrelated to my previous comment. My comment exactly was about window/level. In your comment, you propose the last step is window/level. I proposed the level can be just between 0 to 255 not other value, because of my iPad space color. So what does 500 mean for level value if I have 8 bit color space?

Comment: Level applies to the original range of values. That range can go from -2000 to 2000 (just an example). If you decide to center on 400 (WC = 400) having a Width of 300 (WW = 300) your final values will be 0 (black) for original values lower than 250 (400 - 300/2) and 255 (white) for original values higher than 550 (400 + 300/2). For the values on the interval (250..550), you will have a linear transformation translating these values to your allowed range (0..255).

Comment: Exactly, in your example you always can change WC and WW not level, but in MIM it changes the level value too!

Comment: Window Center and Window Level are often interchanged and used as synonymous. So, **WC = WL**

Comment: It depends on your monitor, if it support 12bits (Eizo, barco) already why would you need to do anything ? Applying Window Level is definitely the correct solution, but "MUST" is a bit too strong IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it by dividing each pixel by a value (max value in the matrix or brightest  / 256), then each pixel became an 8 bit value. And it gave same result when I apply pseudo equation mentioned in https://www.dabsoft.ch/dicom/3/C.11.2.1.2/.

```
const void *bytes = [data bytes];
NSMutableData* ary = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];  
int maxValue = 4087/256; //its a dummy value, use your max value in image instead of 4087
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [data length]; i += sizeof(int16_t)) {
    UInt16 elem = OSReadLittleInt16(bytes, i);

    UInt8 temp = round(elem/maxValue);

    [ary appendBytes:&temp length:sizeof(UInt8)];
```

}

Use 'ary' to make your image.

Comment: You are just applying a particular case of "automatic" window leveling: In your case, WW = Bmax, and WC = Bmax / 2, (*) Bmax = Max brigthness. You could improve this method doing a similar operation for the minimum values, so you will end up having: WW = Bmax - Bmin and WC = (Bmax + Bmin) / 2