# DICOM Convert 16 bit to 8bit

Tags: pixel, dicom

Big Trees:
  I deeply want to find the solution of follow question:
  I want to convert the pixeldata of dicom file to 8bit(byte[]) which the file BitsAllocated was 16bit.
  whatever it's the Grayscale or Color.
  also I know the Color's SimplePerPixel is 3.

3Q!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show legally DICOM 16 unsigned integer on the device are supporting 8 bit unsigned integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401127/how-to-show-legally-dicom-16-unsigned-integer-on-the-device-are-supporting-8-bit)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply take the pixel data and transform it to 8 bit (unless you are sure that all the values are ALREADY in the range supported by a byte).
This because you would alter important data: the Dicom file may store the pixel data in visual density units or Hounsfield units, and modifying the values may screw up things.

You can apply the transformation to 8 bits to the presentation data, the values resulting from the modality VOI/LUT and presentation VOI/LUT transformations.

This [example](http://imebra.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/imebra_build_2013-07-16_08-42-08/html/dicom2jpeg_2dicom2jpeg_8cpp-example.html) that uses the [imebra](http://imebra.com) library uses the presentation data to obtain a 8 bits per color channel image, that is then saved in jpeg format.
Modify the color space from YBR_FULL to RGB in both the color transform and the image allocation in order to get an RGB image.

Example (in case the link changes):

```
/*

Imebra 2011 build 2013-07-16_08-42-08

Imebra: a C++ Dicom library

Copyright (c) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013 by Paolo Brandoli/Binarno s.p.
All rights reserved.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as published by
 the Free Software Foundation.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA

-------------------

If you want to use Imebra commercially then you have to buy the commercial
 support available at http://imebra.com

After you buy the commercial support then you can use Imebra according
 to the terms described in the Imebra Commercial License Version 1.
A copy of the Imebra Commercial License Version 1 is available in the
 documentation pages.

Imebra is available at http://imebra.com

The author can be contacted by email at info@binarno.com or by mail at
 the following address:
 Paolo Brandoli
 Rakuseva 14
 1000 Ljubljana
 Slovenia



*/

#include <iostream>


#include "../../library/imebra/include/imebra.h"
#include <sstream>

#ifdef PUNTOEXE_WINDOWS
#include <process.h>
#else
#include <spawn.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#endif

#include <memory>
#include <list>

using namespace puntoexe;
using namespace puntoexe::imebra;

int findArgument(const char* argument, int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(int scanArg(0); scanArg != argc; ++scanArg)
    {
            if(std::string(argv[scanArg]) == argument)
            {
                    return scanArg;
            }
    }
    return -1;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::wstring version(L"1.0.0.1");
    std::wcout << L"dicom2jpeg version " << version << std::endl;

    try
    {

            if(argc < 3)
            {
                std::wcout << L"Usage: dicom2jpeg dicomFileName jpegFileName [-ffmpeg FFMPEGPATH FFMPEGOPT]" << std::endl;
                std::wcout << "dicomFileName        = name of the dicom file" << std::endl;
                std::wcout << "jpegFileName         = name of the final jpeg file" << std::endl;
                std::wcout << "-ffmpeg FFMPEGPATH   = launches FFMPEG after generating the jpeg images." << std::endl;
                std::wcout << " FFMPEGPATH is the path to FFMPEG" << std::endl;
                std::wcout << " FFMPEGOPT are the options for ffmpeg" << std::endl;
                std::wcout << " The input images and the frame rate are added automatically to the options" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            // Separate the extension from the file name
            std::string outputFileName(argv[2]);
            std::string extension;
            size_t dotPos(outputFileName.rfind('.'));
            if(dotPos != outputFileName.npos)
            {
                    extension = outputFileName.substr(dotPos);
                    outputFileName.erase(dotPos);
            }
            else
            {
                    extension = ".jpg";
            }

            // Check for the -ffmpeg flag
            int ffmpegFlag(findArgument("-ffmpeg", argc, argv));
            size_t framesCount(0);
            ptr<dataSet> loadedDataSet;

            try
            {

                // Open the file containing the dicom dataset
                ptr<puntoexe::stream> inputStream(new puntoexe::stream);
                inputStream->openFile(argv[1], std::ios_base::in);

                // Connect a stream reader to the dicom stream. Several stream reader
                //  can share the same stream
                ptr<puntoexe::streamReader> reader(new streamReader(inputStream));

                // Get a codec factory and let it use the right codec to create a dataset
                //  from the input stream
                ptr<codecs::codecFactory> codecsFactory(codecs::codecFactory::getCodecFactory());
                loadedDataSet = codecsFactory->load(reader, 2048);


                // Get the first image. We use it in case there isn't any presentation VOI/LUT
                //  and we have to calculate the optimal one
                ptr<image> dataSetImage(loadedDataSet->getImage(0));
                imbxUint32 width, height;
                dataSetImage->getSize(&width, &height);


                // Build the transforms chain
                ptr<transforms::transformsChain> chain(new transforms::transformsChain);

                ptr<transforms::modalityVOILUT> modalityVOILUT(new transforms::modalityVOILUT(loadedDataSet));
                chain->addTransform(modalityVOILUT);

                ptr<transforms::colorTransforms::colorTransformsFactory> colorFactory(transforms::colorTransforms::colorTransformsFactory::getColorTransformsFactory());
                if(colorFactory->isMonochrome(dataSetImage->getColorSpace()))
                {
                    // Convert to MONOCHROME2 if a modality transform is not present
                    if(modalityVOILUT->isEmpty())
                    {
                        ptr<transforms::colorTransforms::colorTransform> monochromeColorTransform(colorFactory->getTransform(dataSetImage->getColorSpace(), L"MONOCHROME2"));
                        if(monochromeColorTransform != 0)
                        {
                            chain->addTransform(monochromeColorTransform);
                        }
                    }

                    ptr<transforms::VOILUT> presentationVOILUT(new transforms::VOILUT(loadedDataSet));
                    imbxUint32 firstVOILUTID(presentationVOILUT->getVOILUTId(0));
                    if(firstVOILUTID != 0)
                    {
                        presentationVOILUT->setVOILUT(firstVOILUTID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Run the transform on the first image
                        ptr<image> temporaryImage = chain->allocateOutputImage(dataSetImage, width, height);
                        chain->runTransform(dataSetImage, 0, 0, width, height, temporaryImage, 0, 0);

                        // Now find the optimal VOILUT
                        presentationVOILUT->applyOptimalVOI(temporaryImage, 0, 0, width, height);
                    }
                    chain->addTransform(presentationVOILUT);
                }

                std::wstring initialColorSpace;
                if(chain->isEmpty())
                {
                    initialColorSpace = dataSetImage->getColorSpace();
                }
                else
                {
                    ptr<image> startImage(chain->allocateOutputImage(dataSetImage, 1, 1));
                    initialColorSpace = startImage->getColorSpace();
                }

                // Color transform to YCrCb
                ptr<transforms::colorTransforms::colorTransform> colorTransform(colorFactory->getTransform(initialColorSpace, L"YBR_FULL"));
                if(colorTransform != 0)
                {
                    chain->addTransform((colorTransform));
                }

                ptr<image> finalImage(new image);
                finalImage->create(width, height, image::depthU8, L"YBR_FULL", 7);

                // Scan through the frames
                for(imbxUint32 frameNumber(0); ; ++frameNumber)
                {
                    if(frameNumber != 0)
                    {
                        dataSetImage = loadedDataSet->getImage(frameNumber);
                    }


                    if(chain->isEmpty() && dataSetImage->getDepth() != finalImage->getDepth() && dataSetImage->getHighBit() != finalImage->getHighBit())
                    {
                        chain->addTransform(new transforms::transformHighBit);
                    }

                    if(!chain->isEmpty())
                    {
                        chain->runTransform(dataSetImage, 0, 0, width, height, finalImage, 0, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        finalImage = dataSetImage;
                    }

                    // Open a stream for the jpeg
                    const std::wstring jpegTransferSyntax(L"1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.50");
                    std::ostringstream jpegFileName;
                    jpegFileName << outputFileName;
                    if(frameNumber != 0 || ffmpegFlag >= 0)
                    {
                            jpegFileName << "_" << frameNumber;
                    }
                    jpegFileName << extension;
                    ptr<puntoexe::stream> jpegStream(new puntoexe::stream);
                    jpegStream->openFile(jpegFileName.str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
                    ptr<puntoexe::streamWriter> jpegWriter(new streamWriter(jpegStream));
                    ptr<codecs::codec> outputCodec(codecsFactory->getCodec(jpegTransferSyntax));

                    // Write the jpeg image to the stream
                    outputCodec->setImage(jpegWriter, finalImage, jpegTransferSyntax, codecs::codec::veryHigh,
                            "OB", 8, false, false, false, false);

                    ++framesCount;
                }

            }
            catch(dataSetImageDoesntExist&)
            {
                    // Ignore this exception. It is thrown when we reach the
                    //  end of the images list
                    exceptionsManager::getMessage();
            }

            // All the images have been generated.
            // Should we launch FFMPEG?
            if(ffmpegFlag >= 0 && framesCount != 0)
            {
                    // List of arguments to be passed to ffmpeg
                    typedef std::list<std::string> tOptionsList;
                    tOptionsList options;

                    // The first argument is the application's name
                    options.push_back(argv[ffmpegFlag + 1]);

                    // Calculate the frames per second from the available tags
                    double framesPerSecond(0);
                    double frameTime(loadedDataSet->getDouble(0x0018, 0, 0x1063, 0));
                    if(frameTime > 0.1)
                    {
                            framesPerSecond = 1000 / frameTime;
                    }
                    if(framesPerSecond < 0.1)
                    {
                            framesPerSecond = loadedDataSet->getUnsignedLong(0x0018, 0x0, 0x0040, 0x0);
                    }
                    if(framesPerSecond < 0.1)
                    {
                            framesPerSecond = loadedDataSet->getUnsignedLong(0x0008, 0x0, 0x2144, 0x0);
                    }

                    // Add the ffmpeg argument for the frames per second
                    if(framesPerSecond > 0.1)
                    {
                            options.push_back("-r");
                            std::ostringstream frameRate;
                            frameRate << framesPerSecond;
                            options.push_back(frameRate.str());
                    }

                    // Add the ffmpeg argument for the input files
                    options.push_back("-i");
                    options.push_back(outputFileName + "_%d" + extension);

                    // Add the ffmpeg argument for the number of frames
                    options.push_back("-dframes");
                    std::ostringstream frameCount;
                    frameCount << (unsigned long)framesCount;
                    options.push_back(frameCount.str());

                    // Add the arguments specified when dicom2jpeg was launched
                    for(int copyArguments(ffmpegFlag + 2); copyArguments < argc; ++copyArguments)
                    {
                            options.push_back(argv[copyArguments]);
                    }

                    // Build the arguments array
                    std::auto_ptr<const char*> ffArgv(new const char*[options.size() + 1]);
                    size_t insertPosition(0);
                    for(tOptionsList::iterator scanOptions(options.begin()); scanOptions != options.end(); ++scanOptions, ++insertPosition)
                    {
                            ffArgv.get()[insertPosition] = (*scanOptions).c_str();
                    }
                    ffArgv.get()[options.size()] = 0;

                    // Launch ffmpeg
#ifdef PUNTOEXE_WINDOWS
        return (int)_spawnvp(_P_WAIT , argv[ffmpegFlag + 1], ffArgv.get());
#else
        char *environment[] = {0};

        pid_t process_id;
        posix_spawnp (&process_id, argv[ffmpegFlag + 1],
                        0, 0, (char* const*)ffArgv.get(), (char* const*)environment);
        wait(0);
#endif

            }

            return 0;

    }
    catch(...)
    {
            std::wcout << exceptionsManager::getMessage();
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Let's assume we have 16 bit dicom image of winodw centre L and window width W , if we convert it to 8 bit negative image , what should be the formula to converting this